# Why does PHP output different error messages for these two cases?

Tags: php

It may not be the best practice, but in PHP we are allowed to define classes at the bottom of files However,

```
$t = new Test();

$t->foo();

class Test extends FakeInvalidClass  {
    public function foo(){
        echo "arrived in foo.";
    }
}
```

Produces error message:

`Fatal error: Class 'Test' not found in /mysite/test.php on line 4`

That's odd... class 'Test' is defined at the bottom of the file, PHP should have failed because `FakeInvalidClass` was not found, not `Test`

```
<?php
// test.php

class Test extends FakeInvalidClass  {
    public function foo(){
        echo "arrived in foo.";
    }
}

$t = new Test();

$t->foo();
```

Produces a more human readable error

`Fatal error: Class 'FakeInvalidClass' not found in /mysite/test.php on line 4`

For reference, this works just fine:

```
<?php
// test.php

$t = new Test();

$t->foo();

class Test {
    public function foo(){
        echo "arrived in foo.";
    }
}
```

Comment: One note: in your second example (the one where the class is at the top) the error message IS NOT produced as a result of `$t = new Test()` but rather because PHP parsed the Test class, attempting to add it to its internal class registry, and couldn't find its extended class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it'll all make sense to you when you see the opcodes Zend Engine generates for each example (it does for me anyway).

**Example 1:**

```
compiled vars:  !0 = $t
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   4     0  >   EXT_STMT                                                 
         1      ZEND_FETCH_CLASS                                 :0      'Test'
         2      EXT_FCALL_BEGIN                                          
         3      NEW                                              $1      :0
         4      DO_FCALL_BY_NAME                              0          
         5      EXT_FCALL_END                                            
         6      ASSIGN                                                   !0, $1
   6     7      EXT_STMT                                                 
         8      ZEND_INIT_METHOD_CALL                                    !0, 'foo'
         9      EXT_FCALL_BEGIN                                          
        10      DO_FCALL_BY_NAME                              0          
        11      EXT_FCALL_END                                            
   7    12      EXT_STMT                                                 
        13      ZEND_FETCH_CLASS                                 :6      'FakeInvalidClass'
        14      ZEND_DECLARE_INHERITED_CLASS                     $7      '%00test%2Fhome%2Fflacroix%2Ftest.php0x7f756fea4055', 'test'
  12    15    > RETURN                                                   1
```

As you can see #1 gets the `Test` class, which in turn goes to #13 to get the `FakeInvalidClass` (see the `return :6` there). Since the latter is not defined, #13 fails and return to #1, which also fails because `Test` is left undefined.

Both of them (#13 and #1) will call `zend_error` (as evidenced in the PHP source), but `zend_error` has global state (i.e.: errors are not stacked) so any subsequent call will overwrite the error message with the new one. So, in pseudo code:

```
ZEND_FETCH_CLASS('Test')
    ZEND_FETCH_CLASS('FakeInvalidClass')
        zend_error('Class FakeInvalidClass not found')
        return
    zend_error('Class Test not found')
    return
```

**Example 2:**

```
compiled vars:  !0 = $t
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   4     0  >   EXT_STMT                                                 
         1      ZEND_FETCH_CLASS                                 :0      'FakeInvalidClass'
         2      ZEND_DECLARE_INHERITED_CLASS                     $1      '%00test%2Fhome%2Fflacroix%2Ftest2.php0x7fe2c1461038', 'test'
  10     3      EXT_STMT                                                 
         4      ZEND_FETCH_CLASS                                 :2      'Test'
         5      EXT_FCALL_BEGIN                                          
         6      NEW                                              $3      :2
         7      DO_FCALL_BY_NAME                              0          
         8      EXT_FCALL_END                                            
         9      ASSIGN                                                   !0, $3
  12    10      EXT_STMT                                                 
        11      ZEND_INIT_METHOD_CALL                                    !0, 'foo'
        12      EXT_FCALL_BEGIN                                          
        13      DO_FCALL_BY_NAME                              0          
        14      EXT_FCALL_END                                            
  13    15    > RETURN                                                   1
```

Here #1 is a `ZEND_FETCH_CLASS 'FakeInvalidClass'` code, but the class doesn't exist, so it returns a `FakeInvalidClass not found` message, as it should.

**Example 3:**

```
compiled vars:  !0 = $t
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   4     0  >   EXT_STMT                                                 
         1      ZEND_FETCH_CLASS                                 :0      'Test'
         2      EXT_FCALL_BEGIN                                          
         3      NEW                                              $1      :0
         4      DO_FCALL_BY_NAME                              0          
         5      EXT_FCALL_END                                            
         6      ASSIGN                                                   !0, $1
   6     7      EXT_STMT                                                 
         8      ZEND_INIT_METHOD_CALL                                    !0, 'foo'
         9      EXT_FCALL_BEGIN                                          
        10      DO_FCALL_BY_NAME                              0          
        11      EXT_FCALL_END                                            
   8    12      EXT_STMT                                                 
        13      NOP                                                      
  13    14    > RETURN                                                   1
```

Zend gets a `ZEND_FETCH_CLASS 'Test'` code and execute normally.

This is explained by the fact that PHP will parse *first-level* classes it encounters in the code *before* it executes it. When you create a class definition that extends another class or instantiate an object, a `ZEND_FETCH_CLASS` opcode will be inserted for that class at that point in the code. It's actually *lazy-initialization*.

This is also evidenced by the fact that this works perfectly:

```
<?php

exit;

class Test extends FakeInvalidClass  {
    public function foo(){
        echo "arrived in foo.";
    }
}
```

**Conclusion:**

The different error messages are explained by the different parameters to the `ZEND_FETCH_CLASS` opcode.

Now, if you wonder why ZE generates opcodes like that, it's probably a design choice, it's probably easier to maintain. But to be honest, I have no idea.

Comment: +1 How are you generating these bytecode reports? I'd like to try it as well.

Comment: Very nice - I'd also like to know how to generate these reports :)

Comment: @webbiedave: @Mike B: @ANisus: It's with the [vld extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/vld). Once you activate it, you can generate opcodes and other useful info with `php -d vld.active=1 -d vld.execute=0 -f file.php`.

Answer (score 5):

The logical conclusion is that if you try to create an object of a class, it will continue to scan the rest of the file for this class declaration. If it fails to 'parse' the class (due to the fact that you extend an unexisting class), it will return to the line where you tried to create the object and tell you that the class doesn't exist.

So why not giving you an error when not finding the class that you extend?

Well, PHP doesn't know if you later on will include a file which would contain `FakeInvalidClass`, and it would be wrong to say at line 4 that `Fatal error: Class 'FakeInvalidClass' not found`.

**Edit:**
However, you can't include `FakeInvalidClass` later on since `Test` will already have been parsed. So, it still remains that PHP will give you the error on the line it fails to execute. But a more informative error message would have been to stack them:

`Class 'Test' not found (Class 'FakeInvalidClass' not found in /mysite/test.php on line 8) in /mysite/test.php on line 4`

But PHP doesn't stack errors.

Comment: don't know if it's correct but +1 for the logical conclusion. It could be a performance optimization to not do a read ahead for extension classes because it's expensive.

Comment: @Paystey: Hehe. True, but it would be very hard to do a read ahead if you later on might have conditions that determine if the `FakeInvalidClass.php` file will be included or not. So at the time of the object creation, PHP seems to classify that Test doesn't exist, but will start to exist as soon as FakeInvalidClass exists.

Comment: Your last paragraph makes a lot of sense (not that the rest doesn't :p). Consider the circumstance where additional files are included conditionally. PHP can't always parse a file and any included files before executing code.. included code needs to be parsed at run-time. So, there's no way for PHP to know what classes will be available to it simply by parsing a file.. it has to evaluate it as well.

Comment: @MikeB: Exactly, that was my thought (see comment to Paystey). After all, it could be the `FakeInvalidClass` from file1.php or perhaps file2.php depending on later inclusions.

Comment: ANisus, I think it *SHOULD* fail at the point where it finds Test which extends FakeInvalidClass, because you can never define parent classes AFTER child classes. This is the misleading part. In fact, this example still produces the same error I have require "FakeInvalidClass.php" at the top of the file that actually contains the FakeInvalidClass definition.

Comment: OK there is 1 case where you can define a parent class after a child class, and that is through an autoloader, which technically will load the parent class first anyway, then continue loading the child class.

Comment: @MichaelButler The point is that it isn't failing because Test doesn't exist yet because PHP can't find its parent class. So it holds off on creating the class definition. But then you go and screw everything up by creating it and PHP class definitions know nothing about it :p

Comment: I'm surprised http://codepad.org/9lfFLaFd still produces `class 'Test' not found`

Comment: @MichaelButler: Is that so? Oh! Now I am curious enough to try it out myself :) . Since if what you say is correct, then my assumption is wrong.

Comment: @MikeB , ANisus yes, that is where this starts getting weird. I guarantee the average PHP programmer will look at that codepad example and say it won't produce an error because all necessary classes are defined. But it does fail :)

Comment: @MichaelButler: It is true as you (and MikeB) says. Then the answer would probably is that PHP gives you that error message because that was the line where the error appeared as netcoder points out.

Answer (score 3):

Just cause in your first case, the class "Test" isn't load. In the second case, the class is load but the extend is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: 
     you try to create an object of the class Test so when it tries to create an object the extension from the base class FakeInvalid class hence the error in creating Test class saying it isnt found.

Case 2: it first tries to extend the base class and doesnt find it so gives that error saying FakeInvalidClass not found.